# How should duplicate answers be handled when user deletes to remove downvotes?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

See the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48984624/4875631):

[image]

The user deleted his answer, and then recreated it exactly (I'm assuming to avoid the downvote on his answer he had received before he edited his post). How should this be handled? Should this be mod flagged?

Comment: Why do you have "timeline" and "advanced flagging"?

Comment: @user202729: The timeline is from this userscript: ["SEModifications.user.js"](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts). Advanced flagging probably is a userscript too.

Comment: that's stupid from the answerer to do that. If the answer is average, sometimes a -1 can attract corrective upvotes. Deleting the answer & posting the same kills this possibility...

Comment: Is this the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48986948), with [this deleted original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959924)? (... Which, incidentally, also answered a horrible question – so if you are going to go there, please vote to close it as well. Thanks for your time.)

Comment: @usr2564301 It does appear so.

Comment: If low rep users delete too many of their posts, they will eventually auto-ban themselves. There's some manner of auto-ban kicking in if the reputation/deleted posts ratio gets too high. For users with several hundred rep points, this shouldn't be much of an issue. But for lower rep users, I believe it is.

Comment: I laughed audibly at this! It's impressive how much people care about their SO rep yet care so little about ensuring they don't post garbage to begin with. What was this person's thought process anyways? "Hopefully the intelligent voters have left by now so now is my chance to score some points with stragglers."??

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think it was more geared toward the fact he received a downvote before the post was edited. I think they felt like because they edited it, they didn't deserve the downvote, so they took the matter into their own hands.

Comment: @CalvT븃 Is there a reason why you edited my post to a stack link? It was a completely superfluous edit.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is basically "cheating" the system.
Flag the new answer with a custom flag, explaining the situation.

The mod flag will serve as a marker on their account. If a users does this systematically, they will be penalized.

Comment: Also, that question is "Too Broad".

Comment: Its practically the same answer.. User is likely to attract downvotes for the same reasons and dig themselves into a rate limit on answering or bans

Comment: @SurajRao: It's _literally_ the same. But yes, he's only digging a deeper hole for himself. The new answer has now also been deleted, let's see if he goes for number 3.

Comment: The user is trying to cheat the system because the system is unfair: it attaches negative votes, which a bad version of an answer rightfully earned, to a newer (supposedly better) version.

Comment: @anatolyg so, just because life isn't fair, it's suddenly okay to break the rules? Sorry, but that's a very poor excuse.

Comment: This is not an excuse. I just point out an important part that this post overlooks.

Comment: Yes it's an excuse. If I think a speed limitation on a certain road isn't "fair", and I decide to drive too fast, a police officer will still fine me if I tell him it's not fair.

Comment: @anatolyg the system is neither fair nor unfair, it is simply the system.

Comment: There is some automated mechanism that addresses this no? If a user was a repeat offender of this e.i. not caught by other users, they will get penalized by not being allowed to answer more or some such thing.

Comment: @Matt: I think only the "normal" question ban mechanism exists to handle this.

Comment: @anatolyg You are wrong. If the new answer is *identical* to the new one, then **yes** it does *deserve* the downvotes. If the user would have provided a *different* answer, then it would have been perfectly fine (provided he did not just copy&paste someone else's answer...)

Comment: See text "I'm assuming to avoid the downvote on his answer he had received before he edited his post". This seems a reasonable assumption, though we can't verify it without extensive digging around.

Comment: @Cerbrus If the speed limit is unfair, maybe the speed limit should be changed. This is Meta. Discussing such things is completely on-topic here.

Comment: @anatolyg That's part of why upvotes are worth 10 rep and downvotes are only worth -2.  If you improve your downvoted answer, it takes only 1/5 as many upvotes to cancel out the downvote rep.  This guy just wants to eat his cake and have it too.

Comment: @Ajedi32: That's not what's going on here. The author of the downvoted answer didn't go to meta to discuss changing the rules ("fairness") of SO. He just _broke_ the rules, instead.

Comment: @anatolyg: What digging around is there left to do? The two answers are ___exact duplicates___. This is a relatively common thing. I mean, what possible other reason could anyone have to delete and re-post their answer? There isn't any.

Comment: @Cerbrus But anatolyg is not the author of the downvoted answer, and he _is_ on meta discussing the rules. I agree there's no need for you to mention the "fairness" of the rules one way or the other in your answer, I just disagree with your characterization of his points here as an "excuse".

Comment: Calling something "unfair" is unconstructive, @Ajedi32. It is just an opinion that wasn't backed by anything substantial. Instead of writing an answer with his point of view, he commented on _my_ answer with an (imo) misguided perception of how SO works. I am free to respond saying that "fairness" is a poor excuse for the behaviour. I ___never___ claimed their comments were off-topic. I just strongly disagreed.

Comment: Agreed. Downvotes don't retroactively become obsolete when content is edited. They were placed there when the content was not good. If the content is then edited: great! But that does not imply anything got better, that is for future voters to decide. The proper way forward is that existing downvotes get cancelled out with new upvotes, existing votes being changed is merely a bonus. Or none of that happens, because editing does not imply improvement; the existing downvotes may still be valid post-edit. What happened here was wrong because it was at best presumptuous. And at worst cheating.